# Implement interface using custom ScrollView class - Android

Tags: java, android, interface

I need to know when the user scroll up or down. I managed to achieve that but now I am stuck getting the result back to my main class where I need it. Specifically I don't know how to pass the results to an interface I created.

Here is the error I get:

> Attempt to invoke interface method 'void
>   com.app.android.interfaces.ScrollDirection.Down(int)' on a
>   null object reference

And here is my custom ScrollView:

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private ScrollDirection scrolldirection;

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        scrolldirection = (ScrollDirection) context;
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
        super.onScrollChanged(scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY);
        if(scrollY<oldScrollY){
            scrolldirection.Down(1);
        }else{
            scrolldirection.Down(-1);
        }
    }

    public interface ScrollDirection{
        public void Down(int direction);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it seems `scrolldirection` has not been initialized. Hence the `NullPointerException`. Put  debug point in your constructor and have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add this line `scrolldirection = (ScrollDirection) context;` inside every constructor

```
public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    scrolldirection = (ScrollDirection) context;
}

public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    scrolldirection = (ScrollDirection) context;
}
```

To allow Android Studio to interact with your view, at a minimum you must provide a constructor that takes a Context and an AttributeSet object as parameters

[Docs link](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

**Update :** The recent issue was the implementation of `CustomScrollView` inside `Fragment` but `Fragment` do not have their `context`. To implement this ,make parent `Activity` `implements` the `ScrollDirection` and make some function in `Fragment` and call them from `Activity's` `Down` function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get this error when using this code: Binary XML file line #84: Binary XML file line #84: Error inflating class com.app.android.supportClass.CustomScrollView.

Comment: try clean and run option

Comment: The only thing that I changed is the ScrollView in xml to com.app.android.supportClass.CustomScrollView

Comment: supportClass is the package I used to store CustomScrollView

Comment: in your` XML`  it should be  like this `<your_class_packagename.CustomScrollView`

Comment: @student either it's a package name issue in XML or you need to clean the code you can add complete java code and XML if problem still not solved

Comment: When I add the CustomScrollView to my main class, I imported automatically the path. It's this path: import com.app.android.supportClass.CustomScrollView;

Comment: So I need to use <com.app.android.supportClass.CustomScrollView in my xml?

Comment: @student take a look at this demo https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_components.htm , will help you , just see how you can use it in XML and in your activity , ask if you have doubts

Comment: I can't spot any difference from what I am doing

Comment: My code is huge, I don't know where to begin. I found that when I view my xml at the right there is an error: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to com.app.android.supportClass.CustomScrollView$ScrollDirection

Comment: This is the line where I get the error: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);

Comment: It's under: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: you are using this in a fragment and fragment don't have their context so make sure the parent activity implement the `ScrollDirection` and make some function in fragment and call them from activitie's `Down` function

Comment: @student i am glad , that i could help , happy coding